# How to split certain random row values in a specified column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to find who are our top business clients according to total sales and by products. This is easy while using a pivot table. But the problem is data in excel is not clean.
I need to split one column or edit the values in a column so that the branches of a company fall under that company and I can find top company and not divided by branches.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLwwe.png)

As the picture, I need to clean the column group by only  group name like david, kalli, anna. The problem is some of the rows are perfect (Kalli) and some has the issues.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: So is your question about how to clean up column B? If so, then you could have all variations of "Group" in another sheet, and then each variation is assigned a clean Group name. Then use a vlookup to get that clean name as a new column in your data.

Comment: We're not keen on doing your work for you. Can you explain what research you have done and show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

> Simplified question: How do I clean-up a
> text column, keeping only the keyword and discarding numbers or extra
> identifier characters?

**Flash Fill** is a ridiculously underrated feature in Excel that has been around since 2013. It detects patterns and auto completes the data accordingly. To start, manually type the preferred description or format (for the first row only) directly to the right of the text to clean up, e.g.

[image]

Select the empty cell below it and press Data > Flash Fill or press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>**. Excel will auto fill and correct the missing values:

[image]

**Immediately** correct the first occurrence of any mistakes. Note any other action will exit the "Flash Fill" mode. Excel will automatically learn and reapply the Flash Fill. E.g. in the example manually edit and remove "On" from "Kalli On". Excel will respond (while in "Flash Fill" mode) and auto-correct "Kalli ns" to "Kalli":

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have taken the column to another sheet and used text to columns,  and then deleted the extra words and combined the columns again. Then replaced the column in the main data sheet.